# chrome embedded search from another website

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I'm trying to use chrome embedded search function on my web site.

Chrome embedded search can be seen when you open a New Tab in Google Chrome, you see a page with a Google search box where you can type anything. As soon as you start typing in that box, the box disappears and now you typing on the address bar on top. ( you simple press Enter when you are done typing the query )

Can I use the same function on my web page so as soon as user start typing something in a text box on my webpage, it goes to address bar.

Comment: Why not just have a search like here on SO and have it update as you type? Like how you enter tags in a question? Does it have to be in the address bar? What's the benefit to the user?

Comment: @pmac89 that's not what I'm trying to do. Just wanna let the user type the query on to the address bar. Just need to focus the address bar so user types the query to the address bar.

Comment: Look at this: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest